How to handle "429 Too Many Requests" error when importing products from cjdropshipping.com in a Laravel PHP store with Drop-shipping?
HP store with Drop-shipping?
Problem Description:
I'm facing an issue while importing products from cjdropshipping.com in a Laravel PHP store with Drop-shipping. I receive an error message
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientExceptionClient error: GET https://developers.cjdropshipping.com/api2.0/v1/product/list?pageNum=1&pageSize=10 resulted in a 429 Too Many Requests response: {"code":1600200,"result":false,"message":"Too much request, QPS limit is 1 time/1second","data":null,"requestId":"d950aa (truncated...)
Additional Information:
I have successfully added Drop-shipping to the store.
The error message only appears when importing products from cjdropshipping.com.
I have verified that I am entering the correct login credentials for cjdropshipping.com.
Questions I Need Answered:
What is the cause of this error message?
How can I resolve this issue?
Is there a way to increase the request (QPS) limit for cjdropshipping.com?
Are there any alternatives to cjdropshipping.com that do not impose a request limit?
Thank you for your assistance
I have successfully added Drop-shipping to the store.
The error message only appears when importing products from cjdropshipping.com.
I have verified that I am entering the correct login credentials for cjdropshipping.com.
Questions I Need Answered:
What is the cause of this error message?
How can I resolve this issue?
Is there a way to increase the request (QPS) limit for cjdropshipping.com?
Are there any alternatives to cjdropshipping.com that do not impose a request limit?

Their documentation describes this: https://developers.cjdropshipping.com/en/api/api2/standard/limit.html#base-frequency ... consider upgrading to increase to a maximum of 6 requests per second which is still pretty limited.
